# Thickness of G when G is a simple connected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

The **thickness** of a simple graph G is the smallest number of planar subgraphs of G that have G as their union.

Show that if G is a connected simple graph with *v* vertices and *e* edges, where *v* ≥ 3, then the thickness of G is at least ⎡*e*/(3(*v*)-6)⎤.

I am not sure where to even start on this...

Comment: There is a theorem in graph theory that says a planar graph with $v\ge3$ vertices has at most $3v-6$ edges. If $G$ is a union of planar subgraphs, each of these subgraphs has at most $v$ vertices, and therefore at most $3v-6$ edges. If $G$ has $e$ edges, how many of these subgraphs will be needed (at a minimum) to include all $e$ edges? (You have to carry home $e$ eggs in grocery bags. Each bag can hold at most $3v-6$ eggs. You’ll need at least how many bags?)

Comment: Are you talking about 3v≥6+e?

Comment: $e\le 3v-6$ and $3v\ge6+e$ are two ways of stating the same relationship between $e$ and $v$ (that must hold for any planar graph).

Comment: If so, then by algebra you get 1≥e/(3v-6). Which looks like our answer that we have to prove.

Comment: You get $1\ge e/(3v-6)$ if you have one planar graph. The problem you have to solve here involves a number of planar graphs, not necessarily one. Ask yourself the following question. If each planar graph can have up to $3v-6$ edges and no more than that, how many planar graphs will it take, at a minimum, if you need them to have $e$ edges all together?

Comment: Σ _e_ / (3 _v_ -6) ? I really do not know... Your question seems so simple and the answer seems just in my grasp, but I keep drawing a blank.

Comment: Think of something concrete. You have $e$ eggs (edges), and you need to put them into cartons. Each carton can hold 12 eggs. Can you say (in terms of $e$ and 12) how many cartons you’ll need? If you can do that, can you do it again if the cartons held 18 eggs each? If you can do that, what if the cartons held $3v-6$ eggs each?  You have a bunch of edges, and you want to put them into planar graphs, but they may not all fit into one planar graph, because a planar graph can only hold $3v-6$ vertices. You’ve got $e$ edges. How many cartons (I mean planar graphs) might you need?